# Sorting code execution with Q-promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, nonblocking

I have tried to sort my `node.js` code with `Q-promise`:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var Q = require('q');
var companiesUrls = [];
var url = '';
var companiesUrls2 = [];
var carsUrls = [];
var carsOwnerReview = {};
var carReviewUrl = [];
var site = 'http://www.....'
var companiesPath = '/companies'

//step 1
function one() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    request(site+companiesPath, function(err, resp, body){
        if(!err && resp.statusCode == 200){
            console.log("Step 1 request was passed!");
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            $('a', '#group-content').each(function(){
                var url = $(this).attr('href');
                companiesUrls.push(url);
            });
        };
    });
    console.log("step 1 is finished");
    deferred.resolve();
    return deferred.promise;
};

//step 2
function two() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    for(var i=0;i<companiesUrls.length;i+=2){
        companiesUrls2.push(companiesUrls[i]);
    };
    console.log("step 2 is finished");
    deferred.resolve();
    return deferred.promise;
};

//step 3
function three() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    for(var i=0;i<companiesUrls2.length;i++){
        request(site+companiesUrls2[i], function(err, resp, body){
            if(!err && resp.statusCode == 200){
                console.log("Step 3 request was passed!");
                var $ = cheerio.load(body);
                $('h3.edition-title').children().children().each(function(){
                    var url = $(this).attr('href');
                    carsUrls.push(url);
                });
            };
        });
    };
    console.log("step 3 is finished");
    deferred.resolve();
    return deferred.promise;
};

//step 4
function four() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    for(var i=0;i<carsUrls.length;i++){
        carReviewUrl.push(carsUrls[carsUrls.length-1].slice(0,-7)+'/owner-reviews');
    };
    console.log("step 4 is finished");
    deferred.resolve();
    return deferred.promise;
};

//step 5
function five() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    for(var i=0;i<carReviewUrl.length;i++){
        request(site+carReviewUrl[i], function(err, resp, body){
            if(!err && resp.statusCode == 200){
                console.log("Step 5 request was passed!");
                var $ = cheerio.load(body);
                var model = $('#page-title').text();
                $('span.total-votes').children().each(function(){
                    var reviewNum = $(this).text();
                    carsOwnerReview[model] = reviewNum;
                });
            };
        });
    };
    console.log("step 5 is finished");
    deferred.resolve();
    return deferred.promise;
};

//step 6
function six() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    var keysSorted = Object.keys(carsOwnerReview).sort(function(a,b){return carsOwnerReview[a]-carsOwnerReview[b]});
    var keysSortedReversed = keysSorted.reverse();
    console.log("step 6 is finished");
    console.log(carsOwnerReview);
    deferred.resolve();
    return deferred.promise;
};

one()
    .then(two)
    .then(three)
    .then(four)
    .then(five)
    .then(six);
```

So to make my program work correctly I need to run this functions in a sort order, because all of them depends on each other. Here is my expected output:

```
"Step 1 request was passed!"
"step 1 is finished"
"step 2 is finished"
"Step 3 request was passed!"
"step 3 is finished"
"step 4 is finished"
"Step 5 request was passed!"
"step 5 is finished"
"step 6 is finished"
{...}
```

And here is output that my program yielded:

```
"step 1 is finished"
"step 2 is finished"
"step 3 is finished"
"step 4 is finished"
"step 5 is finished"
"step 6 is finished"
{}
"Step 1 request was passed!"
```

**Why is this happening and how can I fix that?**

Comment: Please consider looking at the deferred anti pattern and how to not have it :)

Comment: You are using `deferred.resolve();` at wrong place

Comment: You resolve the deferreds **inside** the callback.

Comment: @Satpal: and where is the right place?

Comment: You need to resolve the deferred _after_ the asynchronous action is complete not before. Moreover don't use promises for sync actions like that.

Comment: __inside__ the callback as @parchment pointed out like `request(url, function(){ //Here });`

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call and http://domenic.me/2012/10/14/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/

Comment: In addition to the deferred anti pattern, you're also suppressing errors here and ignoring them - the correct course of action would be to automatically promisify `request` with `Q.nfbind` and then chain things and use return values. The above code with promises used correctly would not require a single deferred.

Comment: @Satpal: I did put `deferred.resolve();` inside of the callback but now I have this output: "step 1 is finished"\n"step 2 is finished"\n"step 3 is finished"